# How can i use Environment Injector Plugin with Jenkinsfile or Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins declarative file, and adding Jenkins plugin `Environment Injector Plugin`

I use `Environment Injector Plugin` to configure/inject environment variables, the problem is when i try to run `printev` to check available environment variable, nothing added to env variable

I use same plugin for `Freestyle` project and works fine. Can I use `Environment Injector Plugin` with pipeline or not possible at all?

I have try with `echo $VAR_NAME` and `printev` inside pipeline declaration and no luck

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to rely on the environment inject plugin in a declarative Pipeline to set environment variables. You can use an environment block instead. Check [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/) for details.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label '!windows'
    }

    environment {
        DISABLE_AUTH = 'true'
        DB_ENGINE    = 'sqlite'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo "Database engine is ${DB_ENGINE}"
                echo "DISABLE_AUTH is ${DISABLE_AUTH}"
                sh 'printenv'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to set env variable based on the choice parameter. If i use `environment` value will be the same on any choice parameter.

Comment: @apos may be if you add the current Pipeline you have we can give a better answer.